# Matlab - calculating sum of all molecules produced in the interval time

Tags: matlab

I am struggling with the code for calculating the sum of molecules produced in an interval and I think the issue is with establishing the interval the sum is being taken at.

prod_time_seq = total_time as a vector

```
bin_interval= 1;

number_min= 720; 

prod_per_min= zeros(bin_interval,number_min);

for  i=2:number_min  

    int(i) = 1 + ceil((prod_time_seq(i)-prod_time_seq(1))./60); %time interval
    prod_per_min(i) = sum(int(i)); %sum of the molecules of each array
   
end
```

Comment: `int(i)` is only 1 number. 1 number does not define an interval. On top of that, when you `sum`, sou are summing only this number. So you are adding 1 number that you already know. `sum(int(i))` is the same as `int(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to calculate the sum of the elements in each interval, this can be a solution (adding zero as the initial point in the interval of summation):

```
for  i=1:number_min  

int(i) = 1 + ceil((prod_time_seq(i)-prod_time_seq(1))./60); %time interval
prod_per_min(i) = sum(0:int(i)); %sum of the molecules of each array

end
```

In your case, int(i) is a single value and summation will return the value itself. But to be able to create an interval for each case, you need to define a starting point such as 0:int(i), which means the values from zero up to int(i).